# Date parser crashes according to number of digits before 'Z'

Tags: android

I use a Date format which expect this format :

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

All works well when I get date from the API with this format :

```
2013-04-12T16:59:10.234Z
```

But sometimes I get too another format from the API :

```
2013-04-12T16:59:10Z
```

So the parser crashes because it expects to parse ms before 'Z'

So I would to know if there is a way to parse the Date, whatever if there are ms before the 'Z', without implementing a try catch for both tries

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some features of **Java 8** in Android development. It's available [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Try to use **java.time.Instant** for this. It worked fine here in both situations

```
String[] input = new String[]{"2013-04-12T16:59:10Z", "2013-04-12T16:59:10.234Z"};

        for (int x=0 ; x<input.length; x++){
            Instant instant = Instant.parse ( input[x] );
            System.out.println(instant);
        }
```

Comment: Good idea, but I would be interested to do it without using Java 8 for now ;)